# Migrating data to database through gitbash

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I use the laravel framework, and I use git bash to migrate data to my database which I have created(database) before sending the data to the database. But it's throwing an exception:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.  (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema
>   = larabiz and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
>
> at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\larabiz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be
>   made because  the target machine actively refused it. ")
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Comment: Do you start MySQL in XAMPP control panel?

Comment: Please share your `.env` file database configuration details

Comment: yes zahid hasan, i run Mysql in Xampp.

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=larabiz
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

Answer (score 0):

Exception trace:

1 PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ")

Please use the argument -v to see more details.

If the WAMP icon is Orange then one of the services has not started. In your case it looks like MySQL has not started as you are getting the 
message that indicates there is no server running and therefore listening for requests. Look at the mysql log and if that tells you nothing look at the Windows event log, in the Windows -> Applications 
section. Error messages in there are pretty good at identifying the cause of MySQL failing to start.

Sometimes this is caused by a my.ini file from another install being 
picked up by WAMPServers MySQL, normally in the \windows or 
\windows\system32 folders. Do a search for 'my.ini' and 'my.cnf' and if 
you find one of these anywhere outside of the \wamp.... folder structure 
then delete it, or at least rename it so it wont be found. Then restart 
the MySQL service.

Give this a try and post back with the errors you have identified and we shall try to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks @aiden, my issue is solved. but the error was not that.